# Error in Easyapache 4 provision with php-cli

Tags: cpanel, php-7, easyapache-4

I migrated from EasyApache 3 to EasyApache 4 using the migration tool in my shell. Right now, in the WHM, I'm setting the provision but I got an error with php-cli that says

```
Error: Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of ea-php-cli-0.2.0-1.1.1.cpanel.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php70w-cli-7.0.15-1.w6.x86_64
```

How can I solve this? I'm searching a lot of pages but couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to remove that package **php70w-cli-7.0.15-1.w6.x86_64** since that's not an EA4 package (`yum erase php70w-cli-7.0.15-1.w6.x86_64`)

Do a `rpm -qa | grep php` and see what php packages are actually installed on the server.

Are you sure that the migration completed succesfully? Did you use the migration script from a ssh console?

This should be run first, then you can access EasyApache4 from WHM

```
/scripts/migrate_ea3_to_ea4
```

Comment: I did it from a ssh console using the script you said, and now I can see EasyApache 4 in my WHM. Let me try to remove this package